# Extend ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My first foray into modules!

*lib/model_extension/say_hello*

```
module FirstModule
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include FirstModule
end
```

The code in the example raises this error:

```
lib/model_extension/say_hello.rb:5:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)
```

So what does this mean? I need to include ActiveRecord::Base before telling it to include modules? Am I putting the module in the wrong place?

And how should I then include the module in the model?

```
include FirstModule
```

would certainly do the trick, but is this the properway to do it? When you install a gem that alters your models, you include it like this:

```
has_secure_password
```

How should I set it up so I can include a module like that?

Comment: can you show line 16 of the `say_hello` file? i would guess from the error that you have something like `require Activerecord` - it should be `require 'activerecord'`

Comment: @omnikron I do apologise, I took some code out of the question for brevity but copy pasted the error message! It should add up now.

Comment: Aha, so it looks like your reference to `ActiveRecord::Base` is causing the problem, because `ActiveRecord` doesn't exist (so it can't have a subclass `Base`, is what the error is telling you). How are you loading the file? If it's part of a Rails app I would assume that ActiveRecord should be loaded already, but if you're doing something esoteric then maybe a simple `require 'activerecord' at the top of this file would solve it

Comment: @omnikron It's part of a rail's app. Not sure why I'd need `require 'active_record'` but that does fix it. Still feels like I'm missing something..

Comment: It has to do with how rails lazy-loads code, especially in the development environment. In particular file names are important so it might be as simple as changing `say_hello.rb` to `first_module.rb` but it does depend on your individual setup and rails version - you can read more about it [here](http://bjjb.org/R). Possibly it would also work if you removed the `require` and had `ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, FirstModule`.  Take a look at [this answer](http://bjjb.org/S), it might give you some pointers.